# Axios differentiate between local and prod?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

I am using Vue + axios and I am having trouble setting it up so that base url will be different depending on url of the site?

so my localhost for vue is of course:

http://localhost:8080

api for localhost is:

http://webuilder.app

on the server vue is:

http://webuilder.co.uk

and api is:

http://api.webuilder.co.uk

So I am using webpack to combine common libraries:

```
'vendor.js': ['vue', 'bootstrap', 'axios', 'popper.js', 'pace', 'vue-router', 'jquery'],
```

and my global config:

```
import Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js';
import Pace from 'pace-js';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Axios from 'axios';

Pace.start();

try {
  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
  window.Popper = Popper;
  require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.Vue = Vue;
window.VueRouter = VueRouter;

window.axios = Axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

So if I want to do axios post it works fine but each time I have to tell it what domain it is going to, is there some kind of setup so that when I am on localhost, domain is webuilder.app while if it's on prod domain is api.webuilder.co.uk?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using something like this

```
var axios = require('axios');

var axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.baseUrl || 'https://example.com/foo/bar'
});

module.exports = axiosInstance;
```

Use this in a conditional statement where you set the enviroment to prod or develop

Comment: I am not actually setting environment to prod or develop, should have mention that in question but i am using cross env? Does that help? can you update an answer to include that: package.json:     "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"

Comment: `baseURL: '/'` works for same domain well